# Accessing only part of a dictionary in a for using Python

Tags: python

My example dictionary is  this

```
data_dictionary = {1:'blue',2:'green',3:'red',4:'orange',5:'purple',6:'mauve'}
```

The data_dictionary can have more elements depending on the incoming data . The first value is what we call a payload_index. I always get payload_index 1 to 4 .

I need to assemble a list from this. Pretty easy:

```
for payload_index in data_dictionary :
            assembled_packet.append(data_dictionary[payload_index])
```

My problem is I need to always skip the 3rd element. I guess I could do an if but that would be inefficient:

```
for payload_index in data_dictionary :
            if payload_index <> 3:
                assembled_packet.append(data_dictionary[payload_index])
```

I could do it in two steps and do the first three elements but the problem is I cannot figure out how to get the rest since the number of elements after the 3rd varies. I tried using an impossibly high index (below) but that obviously fails:

```
#get element 1 and two
for index in range(0,3):
            assembled_packet.append(data_dictionary[index])

#get element 1 and two
for index in range(4,999):
            assembled_packet.append(data_dictionary[index])
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that `if payload_index <> 3` is inefficient? Have you measured it?

Comment: The dictionary is not necessarily in order - do you mean the item whose key is 3?

Comment: `My problem is I need to always skip the 3rd element`. Be aware that dicts have no order!

Comment: I have not measured it but I have to assume that checking the value every time would be less efficient than knowing where to start. My dictionary is much larger than the example here. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I did mean the element who's key is 3. Sorry.

Comment: @William: *The first value is what we call a payload_index. I always get payload_index 1 to 4 .* Quite clearly in your code, `payload_index` is every key of the dictionary! Where are you getting your `payload_index` from? Is it external to the `data_dictionary`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*inefficient*? That seems like a premature optimisation! Just use normal code:

```
for payload_index in data_dictionary:
    if payload_index != 3:
        assembled_packet.append(data_dictionary[payload_index])
```

or even better:

```
assembled_packet = [data_dictionary[index] for index in data_dictionary if index != 3]
```

Of course, you could just simply do:

```
>>> d = {1:'blue',2:'green',3:'red',4:'orange',5:'purple',6:'mauve'}
>>> d.pop(3)
'red'
>>> list(d.values())        # in py3k; in python-2.x d.values() would do
['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple', 'mauve']
```

P.S. `<>` is long since deprecated.

Comment: +1. Months after the fact, this little "if" statement will probably do more to communicate the intent of the programmer than two strange "for" loops that just happen to omit an element.

Comment: I like `<>` for `not equal`. And please note, it is not **deprecated** - it is [obsolescent](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html)!

Answer (score 1):

To make those for loops work you can do this:

```
# Get the remaining elements
size = len(data_dictionary)
for index in range(4,size):
            assembled_packet.append(data_dictionary[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way i can think of is :

```
output = [elem for elem in data_dictionary.items() if elem[0]!=3]
```

Answer (score 0):

from you answer is not obvious if you want to skip firts three items or just the 3rd item.
if the former is the case, and you are not sure, that your keys are always 1, 2, 3, you can do something like this:

```
keys = list(sorted(data_dictionary.keys()))[3:]
for payload_index in keys:
    assembled_packet.append(data_dictionary[payload_index])
```

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is I need to always skip the 3rd element. I guess I could do an if but that would be inefficient:

This is even more inefficient:

```
for payload_index in data_dictionary :
    ...
        assembled_packet.append(data_dictionary[payload_index])
```

I'd do it this way (Python >= 2.5):

```
assembled.extend(color for (number, color) in data.iteritems() if number != 3)
```

For Python 3.x change iteritems to items.

And don't encode type names/descriptions in variable names. It's evil.

Comment: Thanks. That's not a type name , its what the value is called outside of this context.